# Percent Problem with different answers

Tags: arithmetic, percentages, percentile

We have 81% of our team here today and we have 16 team members. How many members are missing today?

A) 2 B) 3 C) 4 D) 12 E) 13

My answer:

I did $(0.81)(16) = 12.96$ Rounding up that would give us E) 13.

However, I thought about how it said how many members were missing. So wouldn't se have to do $16-13 = 3$. which would give us B) 3? Please help me with this.

Comment: You gave the answer already. You are asked how many members are *missing*. So, B) is correct.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Thank you!

Comment: Maybe a matter of decimals. Because for sure we can not have 12,96 people. But using 0,8125 the result is a natural number.